# How database works in NDK android studio in C++

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-ndk

I'm trying to work with the database through Android studio in C ++, it seems to me that the code works, but the database is not created in the files and I can't figure out if everything works or not...

c++ file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite-amalgamation-3410200/sqlite3.h"

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jchar JNICALL
Java_com_example_smthing_MainActivity_getInt(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    char * err;
    sqlite3* db;
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    sqlite3_open("myDb.db", &db);

    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS algolancer(x1 INT, x2 INT, name varchar(100));", NULL, NULL, &err);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << "error" << err;
    }

    std::string query;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        query = "insert into algolancer VALUES ("+std::to_string(i)+", "+std::to_string(i + 5)+", 'Arsenyi have sex with Polymetal');";
        /*std::string query = "insert into algolancer VALUES (12, 13, 'nadjib');";*/
        std::cout << query << "\n";
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &err);

        if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
            std::cout << "error" << err;
        }

    }

    /*std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;*/
    return query[0];
}


extern "C" JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_com_example_smthing_MainActivity_getBool(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {

    /* Open database */
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    rc = sqlite3_open("BASE", &db);
    /*if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        //Can't open database/
        sqlite3_open_v2(DB_FILE, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
    }*/

    /* Create SQL statement */
    const char *createQuery =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT);";

    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, createQuery, NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        return false;
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return true;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_com_example_smthing_MainActivity_insertBool(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    /* Open database */
    rc = sqlite3_open("BASE", &db);
    /*if (rc) {
        sqlite3_open_v2(DB_FILE, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
    }*/

    /*const char *pCityName = pCityWeather->getName().c_str();*/
    char insertQuery[50];
    strcpy (insertQuery,"INSERT INTO cities (name) VALUES ('");
    strcat (insertQuery, "HUI");
    strcat (insertQuery, "');");
    puts (insertQuery);

    /*delete pCityWeather;*/

    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, insertQuery, NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return true;
}
```

ActivityMain.java

```
package com.example.smthing;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");

        TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
        boolean a = getBool();
        boolean b = insertBool();
        char c = getinfo();
        txt.setText("POLYMETAL " + c);
    }

    private native char getInt();
    private native boolean getBool();
    private native boolean insertBool();
}
```

CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

add_library(
        native-lib
        SHARED
        main.cpp
        sqlite-amalgamation-3410200/sqlite3.c
        sqlite-amalgamation-3410200/sqlite3.h
        sqlite-amalgamation-3410200/sqlite3ext.h
)

find_library(
        native-lib
        log
)

target_link_libraries(
        native-lib
        ${log_lib}
)
```

I run the program, no error is thrown, but the database is not created either